deserializing YAML keys with hyphens into class object C#
I have the following yaml stucture;
cosmetics:
  cosmeticname:
    type: item

    price-lore:
      - ""
      - "&8> &7Price: &a%price%"
      - ""
      - "&8> &7Click to purchase this cosmetic."

but a couple more different keys.
When I try to deserialize this into a the following class:
    public class CosmeticList
    {
        [JsonProperty("cosmetics")]
        public Dictionary<string, Cosmetic> Cosmetics { get; set; }

        public void LoadFromFile()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(@"cosmetics.yml"))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Cosmetics file not found!");
            }

            var reader = new StreamReader(@"cosmetics.yml");
            string ymlstring = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var yaml = new YamlStream();
            yaml.Load(new StringReader(ymlstring));
            var root = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;

            if (!root.Children.TryGetValue(new YamlScalarNode("cosmetics"), out var cosmeticsNode))
            {
                throw new Exception("Missing 'cosmetics' section in YAML file.");
            }

            var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
                .WithNamingConvention(UnderscoredNamingConvention.Instance)
                .Build();
            var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
                .WithNamingConvention(UnderscoredNamingConvention.Instance)
                .IgnoreUnmatchedProperties()
                .Build();

            var cosmeticsYaml = serializer.Serialize(cosmeticsNode);

            Cosmetics = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Cosmetic>>(cosmeticsYaml);
        }
    }

    public class Cosmetic
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price-lore")]
        public string[] PriceLore { get; set; }
    }


It works for all yaml keys, except the ones with a dash - in the key name. I've tried some things like adding the .WithNamingConvention but the issues persists.
Does anyone know how I can fix this? I would prefer not to change up the yaml stucture for this.

I've solved the issue by changing out UnderscoredNamingConvention.Instance with HyphenatedNamingConvention.Instance in the deserializer

If anyone sees this and has any other recommendations to further improve the code feel free to let me know :) I'm starting out with C# so my knowledge is very limited
